# jQuery datatable generic ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery datatables with the following code:

```
$table.DataTable({
    lengthMenu: [10, 25, 50, 100],
    processing: true,
    paging: true,
    ajax: {
        type: "GET",
        url: '',
        data: function(d) {

        },
        dataSrc: function(json) {
            //some logic
            return json.items;
        },
        error: function(jqXHR) {
           
        }
    },
    "columns": [//my columns]
});
```

What I want is to make the ajax request generic like below:

```
$table.DataTable({
    lengthMenu: [10, 25, 50, 100],
    processing: true,
    paging: true,
    ajax: ajaxForDataTable(url, methodType, function (d) { }, dataSrcCallback),
    "columns": [//my columns]
});

function ajaxForDataTable(url, methodType, dataCallback, dataSrcCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: methodType,
        url: baseUrl + url,
        data: dataCallback,
        dataSrc: dataSrcCallback,
        error: function (jqXHR) {}
    });
}

function dataSrcCallback() {
}
```

The above code is working fine and getting response from the server but the **dataSrcCallback** never called (where I am manipulating data) so the datatable never populates with the data (empty). As I am using this table on multiple pages, if I change any logic I have to do it on all the pages. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong over here so I can rectify it and make it works for me?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the docs: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax .

You're suppose to pass a function to the ajax parameter and call the callback method with the data you want to pass to the datatable.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
    callback(
      JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('dataTablesData') )
    );
  }
} );
```